# MS SQL Store Procedure Optimizing

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, optimization

I have attached my query result. How can I optimize this sp? Also do I need to optimize? I can get the result in 0.2 or in some case more.

```
Client Execution Time   18:18:18        18:18:08        18:17:49        18:17:24        18:13:18        
Query Profile Statistics                                            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    281     281     281     50      0       178.6000
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 235     235     235     44      0       149.8000
  Number of SELECT statements   4870        4870        4870        741     13      3072.8000
  Rows returned by SELECT statements    3653        3653        3653        598     37      2318.8000
  Number of transactions    281     281     281     50      0       178.6000
Network Statistics                                          
  Number of server roundtrips   1       1       1       3       3       1.8000
  TDS packets sent from client  1       1       1       3       3       1.8000
  TDS packets received from server  119     110     90      898     78      259.0000
  Bytes sent from client    138     138     138     284     288     197.2000
  Bytes received from server    327491      327491      327491      2861601     197860      808386.8000
Time Statistics                                         
  Client processing time    2755        3793        2364        908     332     2030.4000
  Total execution time  3225        4294        2825        2095        1375        2762.8000
  Wait time on server replies   470     501     461     1187        1043        732.4000
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to say anything about optimization of your code just because you haven't shown any code. There is no telepathists here.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev i agree with you...Its also hard to point to the exact direction from what He has supplied.

Comment: you should add more explanation here i think ..!

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of options you can look at:

**1.SQL Merge**
SQL Merge can be used to perform Inserts, Updates and Deletes in a single statement.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

**2.Output Clause**
The SQL output clause can be used to return any value from ‘inserted’ and ‘deleted’ (New value and Old value) tables when doing an insert or update.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.90).aspx